# Where to access and store EJS Helpers - SailsJS

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs, sails.js

Well,

SailJS's default templateing engine is **EJS** (*Embedded Javascript*)

But I cannot seem to find the place where we can create our own helpers and stuff.

So, do you know where to access & store **EJS** helpers/stuff?

Answer (score 6):

solved:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2162#issuecomment-55866731

config/http.js

```
module.exports.http = {
  // ...
  locals: {
    filters: {
      formatDate: function(date) { }
    }
  }
}
```

config/bootstrap.js

```
_.extend(sails.hooks.http.app.locals, sails.config.http.locals);
```

At some view...

views/test.ejs

```
<%=: created | formatDate %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create file in ./config with name anyname.js and write some EJS helper like these code:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var ejs = require('ejs');

ejs.filters.fromNow = function(date){
  return moment(date).fromNow()
}
ejs.filters.formatDate = function(date){
  return moment(date).format('MMM Do YYYY');
}
ejs.open = '<?';
ejs.close = '?>';
```

Then in layout, view, it should be call

```
<td><?=: post.createdAt | formatDate ?></td>
```

Hope that help!

**Update**

For some reasons, you guys have to install module sails locally to make sense. So just paste to your console:

```
npm i sails
```

regards,

Anh Nguyen

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is through middleware.  Something like:

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '*': function mixinForm(req, res, next) {
     // <%= form() %>
     res.locals.form = function () {
        return '<form action=""></form>';
     };
     next();
  },
}
```

I would also suggest making a feature request for a more integrated approach at: https://trello.com/b/cGzNVE0b/sails-js-feature-requests.