# SailsJS using custom EJS Filters

Tags: javascript, filter, sails.js, ejs

I have created a custom ejs filter following this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064365/where-to-access-and-store-ejs-helpers-sailsjs)

I created the file in /config and added my filter:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var moment = require('moment');

ejs.filters.formatDate = function (date) {
    return moment.date(date).format('dd mm yy hh:ii');
};

ejs.open = '<?';
ejs.close = '?>';
```

However, when using the filter in the ejs template I get the error that **formatDate** is not defined. I am using like so:

`<?= child.lastPost.createdAt | formatDate ?>`

Anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to use a colon in the opening tag

`<?=:`

Comment: I tried this but I'm now getting `Object has no method formatDate`. why?