# How to configure Sails.js to use EJS view helpers?

Tags: sails.js, ejs

I'm totally new to Sails.js and am trying to be able to use EJS's [view helpers](https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/ViewHelpers) (mostly for `link_to` at the moment). I've seen references that it doesn't work out of the box, but I haven't seen any noob-friendy description of *how* to configure Sails.js to use the view helpers. Currently I have a totally bare-bones application generated with `sails new <name>` and not much else.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to access and store EJS Helpers - SailsJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064365/where-to-access-and-store-ejs-helpers-sailsjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [EJS npm module](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) that comes with Sails does not include helpers, which may not be immediately apparent since the Sails.js views documentation links directly to http://embeddedjs.com/. So you must first install the 'express helpers' npm package:

```
npm install express-helpers --save
```

Then, inside your app's config/bootstrap.js, add this inside the bootstrap function:

```
require('express-helpers')(sails.express.app);
```

Restart your app and your view template should now properly render any link_to's.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my Sails app however now I am migrating to the latest release of sails 0.10.0 rc5 and it doesn't work. The error is, TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined. I was wondering if you know how to do it for this release. Thanks.

Comment: Try `sails.hooks.http.app` at 0.10.x.

Comment: I use sails 0.9.x and I get `Error: Cannot find module 'express'` when requiring `express-helpers`.

Comment: I don't understand why we don't have an express object in sails directly since sails is based on express, I see that we have to require express ourselves.

Comment: Yea, super easy to get past `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`, just install express in the app.

   `npm install express`

Answer (score 2):

Sails 0.10.x:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2162#issuecomment-55866731

config/http.js

```
module.exports.http = {
  // ...
  locals: {
    filters: {
      formatDate: function(date) { }
    }
  }
}
```

config/bootstrap.js

```
_.extend(sails.hooks.http.app.locals, sails.config.http.locals);
views/test.ejs
```

At some view...

```
<%=: created | formatDate %>
```